# How to access the returned results from controller

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I am using cakePHP for my project and i have the following Jquery script

```
$.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo $this->Html->url(array("action" => "retrieveVideoFeed"));?>',
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    vid: $v_id
                },
                success: function( data) {
                                            response([data]);
                }
            });
```

Now i want to use the response data from the controller and when i do :

data.example, it should give the value of the json type that is responded by the controller. However, firebug is complaining that data is not defined. If that is the case, how can i use the response data in the ajax? However the firebug is showing the response data. I just need to know how can i use access the responded data from jquery.

Comment: Have you tried adding `console.log(data)` in your success function to see what is getting returned? I'm a little confused, in your question you state that Firebug is saying that data isn't defined, but that it is showing the response data. Also, is there a reason the `data` object is being cast into an array in the `reponse()` function?

Comment: I don't know cakePHP: What does `$this->Html->url(array("action" => "retrieveVideoFeed"));` return?

Comment: $this->Html->url(array("action" => "retrieveVideoFeed")); it is the url of the controller based on cakephp

Comment: hey ima007: basically the json resonse is successful, but i am aint sure how to access the responded data that is returned by the controller

Comment: @madi can you see the json response in the firebug? if yes then can you post that response here ...

Comment: ima007: which means that there is a json response given as i am seeing it from firebug but on success, how can i use to access the data that is returned by the controller?

Comment: Where is your `response` function defined?

Comment: {"apiVersion":"2.1","data":{"id":"Ahg6qcgoay4","uploaded":"2008-03-10T17:30:17.000Z","updated":"2011-10-23T04:17:10.000Z","uploader":"dothetest","category":"Howto","title":"Test Your Awareness: Do The Test","description":"How many passes does the team in white make? Test your awareness and Do the Test! TFL cycling safetly advert! Count the number of passes the ....[not completed version as i can't post all :)]

Comment: when i do var $cur = data.thumbnail.sqDefault; (which is how the json structure is), it is saying that data is undefined :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thsi is the `json` you are getting as you have posted in the comments

```
{
    "apiVersion": "2.1",
    "data": {
        "id": "Ahg6qcgoay4",
        "uploaded": "2008-03-10T17:30:17.000Z",
        "updated": "2011-10-23T04:17:10.000Z",
        "uploader": "dothetest",
        "category": "Howto",
        "title": "Test Your Awareness: Do The Test",
        "description": "How many passes does the team in white make? Test your awareness and Do the Test!"
    }
}
```

access it in the success handler like

```
success:function(data){
alert(data.data.id);
//or
console.log(data.data.id);
}
```

Comment: You are god. You understood exactly my situation :))